# How can I have two separate foreign keys in a single model that associate in the same way with the same other model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have two columns in a location model that should both associate with the user model (a 'created_by' column and an 'updated_by' column).

The relevant part of my Locations 'show' view looks like this at the moment:

```
<p>
    Created on <%= @location.created_at %> by <%= @location.created_by %><br />
    Last updated on <%= @location.updated_at %> by <%= @location.updated_by %>
</p>
```

... which obviously just gives me the IDs that I put in 'created_by' and 'updated_by' respectively.

I've tried the following association:

```
class Location < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user, :foreign_key => "created_by"
    belongs_to :user, :foreign_key => "updated_by"
end
```

... with this in my view:

```
<p>
    Created on <%= @location.created_at %> by <%= @location.user.name %><br />
    Last updated on <%= @location.updated_at %> by <%= @location.user.name %>
</p>
```

... but that just throws a "NoMethodError in Locations#show - undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass"

(*oddly, it does display the correct user's name in both places if the 'created_by' and 'updated_by' user happen to be the same*)

**How can I have two separate foreign keys in a single model that associate in the same way with the same other model?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
class Location < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user_created,:class_name=>"User", :foreign_key => "created_by"
    belongs_to :user_updated,:class_name=>"User", :foreign_key => "updated_by"
end
```

and apply

```
@location.user_created.name and @location.user_updated.name
```

Comment: This looked promising, but I ended up getting the same NoMethodError (listed in the original question)  "undefined method 'name' for nil:NilClass"

Comment: Interestingly, if I keep both of these associations in the model and just use the "created_by" line in 'show', that line works fine, BUT if I do the same with just the "updated_by" line in the 'show', I get the usual NoMethodError.  I've quadruple-checked my models (which are annotated), and my db schema for typos or errors, and haven't found any.  Peculiar...

Comment: ... also, I tried re-ordering the associations in the model, and both ways it was the "updated_by" line in the view that caused the trouble.

Comment: ... and I tried re-ordering the lines in the 'show' view, and both ways it was the "updated_by" line that drew the error.

Comment: ... The "updated_by" column is set right from creation, so there's always an ID in that field (no "updated_by" field is ever nil in the db).

Comment: ... And both "created_by" and "updated_by" are attr_accessible in the location model.

Comment: you should first check @location.user_created is nil or blank. if it is nil and @location.user_created.name it will raise an error. please check it first

Comment: When I check @location.created_by and @location.updated_by, it faithfully returns both of their IDs.  But when I check @location.user_created and @location.user_updated (with your suggested associations in place), I get "#<User:0x00000100eaf640>" and "" respectively.

Comment: Oddly, I have noticed that on locations where "created_by" and "updated_by" refer to the same user id, _**THEN**_ it displays both instances of the name correctly (with your suggested associations and @location.user_created.name and @location.user_updated.name in place)

Comment: @Hitesh My mistake: I checked to see whether the @location.created_by (and the like) were nil, but I neglected to check whether the users they were _associated with_ existed.  They were pointing to users 1 and 2, and 2 happened to have been deleted.  I'll have to be sure to build in protections against this in my app.  **Thanks so much for your help!**

Answer (score 0):

What if you use @location.updated_by.name and @location.created_by.name?

Comment: I've tried that as well, and I got the same error.

I also tried that *after* altering the 'belongs_to' associations like this (for each): belongs_to :created_by, :class_name => "User", :foreign_key => "created_by" ... no dice.